# Cannot return null for non-nullable field, but the field is nullable

Tags: graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I'm trying to create a query which have to return a list of users from my app. The problem is that the users list can be null, as I specified in the returned type for the query:

```
@ObjectType()
export class UsersListResponse {
    @Field(() => [FieldError], { nullable: true })
    errors?: FieldError[];

    @Field(() => [User], { nullable: true })
    users?: User[]

    @Field(() => Boolean, { nullable: true })
    hasMore?: boolean
}
```

The query is:

```
async getUsersList(
        @Ctx() { req }: AppContext,
        @Arg("offset", { nullable: true }) offset?: number,
        @Arg("limit", { nullable: true }) limit?: number,
        @Arg("orderBy", { nullable: true }) orderBy?: string,
        @Arg("orderType", { nullable: true }) orderType?: string,
    ): Promise<UsersListResponse | null> {
       // code
}
```

When the users list is null, I receive this error:

> Cannot return null for non-nullable field UsersListResponse.users.

Comment: Strange... In docs [Type and Fields](https://typegraphql.com/docs/types-and-fields.html) you can customize the nullability of list: _The basic { nullable: true | false } setting only applies to the whole list ([Item!] or [Item!]!), so if we need a sparse array, we can control the list items' nullability via nullable: "items" (for [Item]!) or nullable: "itemsAndList" (for the [Item]) option. Be aware that setting nullableByDefault: true option will also apply to lists, so it will produce [Item] type, just like with nullable: "itemsAndList"._

Comment: Setting `nullable: true` in `users` should be enough to allow `null` as a valid value. Try with `items` or `itemsAndList` and check if something change.

Comment: I've managed to fix it. The problem was inside my query. The ObjectType was correct. Thank you for the advices.